# SVN: Issue with commit-access-control.cfg

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN and trying to learn it. I have setup the SVN server and I am able to check-in/check-out

files from it.
As a next step, I am trying to do access control on it and also trying to add some commit hooks to

prevent some unwanted check-ins.

Here are my svn repositories:

```
/svnrepos/repo1
/svnrepos/repo2
/svnrepos/test    >>>>>>> My test repository for playing around with SVN
```

Now I am trying to do the following using pre-commit:

```
1. Preventing some users to check-in to a directory or any of its sub-folders
2. Preventing some files (say .class files) to be checked in by all users
```

Here is my environment:

```
Perl: v5.14.2 (linux 32-bit )
SVN: 1.7.4  (r1295709)
OS: Linux svnserver 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:54 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I am running the svn server using the command "svnserve -d -r /svnrepos --log-file /var/log/svn.log"

Now I am trying to provide access restrictions to the repository /svnrepos/test. I am trying to 
edit the commit-access-control.cfg file to provide the access restriction. Here are the contents of
this config file:

```
[Make everything read-only for all users]
match   = .*
access  = read-only

[Make test project read-write for admin users ]
match  = ^trunk/svnrepos/test/samplefile.txt
users  = PR111319
access = read-write
```

The following match patterns does not seem to work:

```
match=^trunk/svnrepos/test/samplefile.txt
match=^/svnrepos/test/samplefile.txt
match=/svnrepos/test/samplefile.txt
match=/test/samplefile.txt
match=^/samplefile.txt
```

Whatever match pattern I give, I get the following error while commiting the file samplefile.txt:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: A repository hook failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
/svnrepos/test/hooks/commit-access-control.pl: user `PR111319' does not have permission to commit to 

these paths:
  /
  samplefile.txt
```

However if I give the match as .* then I am able to successfully commit it. From this, I am quite clear that the problem lies with 'match'

Here are the contents of the pre-commit file:

```
68 REPOS="$1"
69 TXN="$2"
70
71 # Make sure that the log message contains some text.
72 SVNLOOK=/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/svnlook
73 $SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
74    grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1
75
76 # Check that the author of this commit has the rights to perform
77 # the commit on the files and directories being modified.
78 /opt/ActivePerl-5.14/bin/perl "$REPOS/hooks/commit-access-control.pl" "$REPOS" "$TXN" "$REPOS/hooks/commit-access-control.cfg" || exit 1
79
80 # All checks passed, so allow the commit.
81 exit 0
```

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks and Regards,
Parasuraman.R

Comment: You seem to be deeply confused about how SVN repositories are organized. I do not even know where to start. `repo1`, `repo2`, and `test` are all served separately by your server. Each repository knows nothing about `svnrepos` directory (it's only specifies the location for the server to know where the repositories are). So any `match` that contains `svnrepos` is nonsensical. The 'expression' `trunk\svnrepos...` - where did you get that `trunk` from? I think you need [to do some further reading](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html).

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Thanks for your reply. The "commit-access-control.cfg" files contains a sample section which shows the following `[However, we don't trust Joe with project1's Makefile]
match  = ^(branches|tags|trunk)/project1/Makefile
users  = joe
access = read-only` that's where I got the word 'trunk'. 
I created the repository using the command `svnadmin create test`. After that I tried to open it in my eclipse using subclipse SVN plugin. From eclipse I connected to that repository using svn://<ip>/test.added samplefile.txt and checked-in the same.

Comment: Hence the file lies just within the repository 'test'. Hence I tried like `^/test/samplefile.txt, ^/samplefile.txt, /test/samplefile.txt, ^trunk/test/samplefile.txt` but all got the same error. I am currently going thru the documentation. Hopefully I will learn the basics :)

Comment: My point was essentially this: what you are trying to do is a fairly advanced usage pattern, you need to get the basics first. Then you'll know e.g. where `trunk` comes from and why it's inappropriate here.  (By the way, in this particular case, it seems you need to give write permissions for `^/` - otherwise you can't commit to that directory).

Comment: Thanks a lot malenkiy_scot. First giving write permission to ^/ and then restricting sub_folders or files worked fine. Thanks a lot again. But still I will go through my basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first:

- You only have a single Subversion repository.

I just want to make this clear. All of your *repositories* will be under the same hook. So, no one can commit to `repos1` or `repos2` unless your hook permits them.

Try using the `svnlook` command since that's what the hook script is using. This will give you a better clue on how to specify your files in your pre-commit hook's configuration file:

```
$ svnlook changed -r $revision $repository_directory
```

The `$repository_directory` is the directory that contains the repository when you did the `svnadmin create` command. You'll need to give it either the relative path or the full path. The `$revision` is the revision number of the Subversion revision you're looking at. Try a few different revisions to see what's being changed You can get the last revision via this command:

```
$ svnlook youngest $repository_directory
```

What you will notice is that there is no `/` at the front of the file's name and that the full path is being specified.

---

I would like to make a few recommendations:

- Since you're new to Subversion, forget the `pre-commit` hook for now. Try using Subversion for a while sans hooks and get an idea how it flows.
- You have `trunk` being specified in your hook, but I don't see `truck` in your repository. I have a feeling you don't quite get the concept of how the standard Subversion repository structure works.

The default use of Subversion is to have three directories called `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` (yes, these are directory names), in the root of your *repository*. In your case, you probably want the following directories since you're treating your single repository as three separate ones:

- `repos1/trunk`
- `repos1/tags`
- `repos1/branches`
- `repos2/trunk`
- `repos2/tags`
- `repos2/branches`
- `test/trunk`
- `test/tags`
- `test/branches`

You create your repository, then before any of your developers can get their grubby little paws on the repository, you create these nine directories. All files in your repository will then be placed under one of these nine directories.

Again, there's no reason why this must be done. If you never branch or tag your code, you really don't have to do this. The directories don't even have to be named `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags`. They could be named `main`, `branches`, `labels` or `moe`, `larry`, `curly` for all Subversion cares.

However, everybody else uses `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags`, and since I'm the type of person who'd jump off the roof if everyone else did, I recommend you too follow the standard naming convention too.

Most development takes place under the `trunk` directory for that *repository*. If you need to create a branch, you can copy the files under `trunk` to the `branches` directory with a particular branch name. For example, I need to create a bug fix branch for release 1.3:

```
$ svn cp svn://localhost/repos1/trunk svn://localhost/repos1/branches/1.3-bug-fixes
```

To tag a file when you do a release, simply copy the directory where you did your work under the `tags` directory:

```
$ svn cp svn://localhost/repos1/trunk svn://localhost/repos1/tags/1.3
$ svn cp svn://localhost/repos1/branches/1.3-bug-fixes svn://localhost/repos1/tags/1.3.1
```

That's how Subversion does tagging and branching. It's different from most version control systems out there, but it has a lot of nice advantages (It's simple, it's easy to find the names of labels and branches via the `svn ls` command, and it gives you a complete history of your branches and tags.)

- Once you get a better understanding how Subversion works and how the repository works, you can then try creating a pre-commit hook. I humbly recommend that you use my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). Unlike the one you're using, it's being actively maintained and is well documented. Plus, it has a lot of nifty features.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the beginning of your answer, it should read "You only have a single Subversion _hook_ ", not "only a single Subversion _repository_".

Comment: @malenkiy_scot - Usually when you use `svnserve`, you're running a single repository which means a single set of hooks.

Comment: this is not true. You can have several repositories (with separate revision counts and which can be moved to different servers separately) and every one having its own set of hooks in its own `hooks` directory. That's what will happen if you use separate `svnadmin create` for them. Now, the usual setup for `commit-access-control.pl` hook is to have it shared and called from `pre-commit` hook in every repository, while having `commit-access-control.cfg` setup per repository. So practically they share a hook (although they do not have to).